# Solving a second Order ODE with a complex coeffcient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, boundary-layer

I have been asked to derive a solution for F(y) in the form F(y) = A cos ky + B sin ky + C , where
k =
(1 + I)/δ
,
δ = sqrt(2ν/ω) and A,B and C are constants to be found.

The ODE I have found is F''+(iω/ν)F+a/ν = 0 with the boundary conditions f(h/2)=f(-h/2) = 0, where a and ω are real constants.

My question is, what are the steps i need to take to solve this ode? and furthermore is my ODE in the correct form such that i will derive a solution for F(y)in the form asked above?

Comment: Do you know how to solve second order constant coefficient ODEs with real coefficients?

Comment: Yes,  i am having trouble with the complex coefficient and also the constant at the end, do I just treat it as homogeneous?

Comment: The equation is not homogeneous, but it is about the simplest inhomogeneous term one could have. My point is that the coefficients being complex should not change how you approach the problem.